# Can I extract a printer driver from a package?

Tags: usb, printing, lubuntu, drivers

I have a printer(Xerox Phaser 3140) that's working perfectly under precise with default drivers from ubuntu. However, when I try to connect it to a netbook running lubuntu precise, this same driver is missing(also on debian on raspberry pi).

I figure this is proprietary software. is there a way to extract the driver from my working ubuntu instalation and move it to the ubuntu install?

Answer (score 1):

I just got a new Xerox and I downloaded the linux driver package from Xerox extracted it and used a file called modelname.PPD.
New to Linux so I don't know if it's the right way but it works :)

[Link to driver](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/phaser-3140/file-download/enza.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en_GB&contentId=104120&from=downloads&viewArchived=false)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [foomatic-ppdfile](http://linux.die.net/man/1/foomatic-ppdfile), which can extract the PPD-file from foomatics compressed database. Then copy this extracted file to your netbook, and tell the latter to use this PPD file for your printer. If the netbook is running [CUPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS), you can do so pointing your web browser to `http://localhost:631/` and use the CUPS web interface to configure your printer.